# unable to create a project azure devops 2019 on premises

Tags: azure-devops, azure-functions, project

I have azure DevOps server on premises, and I want to create a new project but I can't. even though I'm using the admin account. I can create new collection, but I can't create new projects, here's the log when I check it

```
++ Executing - Operation: ProjectCreate, Group: ProjectCreate.TfsTeamBuild
[09:35:38.947] +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
[09:35:38.947] Executing step: Create the Team Project
[09:35:38.947]   Executing step: 'Create the Team Project' Build.CreateTeamProject (7 of 12)
[09:38:43.323]   [Error] The file exists.
[09:38:43.427]   System.IO.IOException: The file exists.
[09:38:43.427]      at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
[09:38:43.427]      at System.IO.Path.InternalGetTempFileName(Boolean checkHost)
[09:38:43.427]      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Server.ProcessTemplate.UpdateCachedProcessParameters(IVssRequestContext requestContext, VersionSpec versionSpec)
[09:38:43.427]      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Server.TeamFoundationBuildService.AddProcessTemplates(IVssRequestContext requestContext, IList`1 processTemplates)
[09:38:43.427]      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Server.TeamFoundationBuildService.CreateBuiltInProcessTemplates(IVssRequestContext requestContext, String teamProjectUri, Boolean isUpgrade)
[09:38:43.427]      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Server.TeamFoundationBuildService.CreateTeamProject(IVssRequestContext requestContext, String projectUri, IList`1 permissions)
[09:38:43.427]      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.Servicing.TFCollection.BuildStepPerformer.CreateTeamProject(ServicingContext servicingContext)
[09:38:43.427]      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationStepPerformerBase.PerformHostStep(String servicingOperation, ServicingOperationTarget target, IServicingStep servicingStep, String stepData, ServicingContext servicingContext)
[09:38:43.427]      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationStepPerformerBase.PerformStep(String servicingOperation, ServicingOperationTarget target, String stepType, String stepData, ServicingContext servicingContext)
[09:38:43.427]      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.ServicingStepDriver.PerformServicingStep(ServicingStep step, ServicingContext servicingContext, ServicingStepGroup group, ServicingOperation servicingOperation, Int32 stepNumber, Int32 totalSteps)
[09:38:43.427] Step failed: Create the Team Project. Execution time: 3 minutes and 4 seconds.
[09:38:43.427]   [StepDuration] 184.3850653
[09:38:43.427]   [GroupDuration] 184.4857136
[09:38:43.777]   [OperationDuration] 204.5521056
[09:38:43.787]   Clearing dictionary, removing all items
```

But there's no existing file the project name is unique. any kind of support it'll be appreciated
thanks & regards

Comment: I had this problem in the past, resolved it somehow, of course I didn't document it, because I hoped it was a one off, but no...  Have you had any luck finding a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to make sure AzureJobAgent in Services is running.  Mine was set to Manual.  Set it to Automatic and it should start when needed.

Comment: thanks for your response, it's already running and it's set to automatic